# WPF C# Bitmap resource as Imagesource for ImageBrush

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, imagesource, imagebrush

I have the bitmap resource Properties.Resources.part1

```
internal static System.Drawing.Bitmap part1 
{
    get 
    {
        object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("part1", resourceCulture);
        return ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(obj));
    }
}
```

How to set this resource to Rectangle.Fill property?

Comment: Is a xaml solution ok for you?

Comment: No, xaml is not accepted, i change this property many times in C# code